# Websocket c# listener as a service

Tags: c#, service, websocket

I am looking at setting up a service that will listen for messages received from multiple websocket servers and eventually kick off other business logic within an existing application with no front end.

As someone completely new to websockets I am undecided as of the best way to implement this.

Does anyone have any experience setting up something similar ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a good tutorial.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) one that use SignalR that use websocket in c#.

Comment: Thank you - I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS then you can use `System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocketContext` to handle `WebSocket` connections through a `IHttpHandler`, sample:

```
/// <summary>
/// Called when a new web socket connection has been established.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="webSocketContext">The web socket context.</param>
public abstract void WebSocketContext(System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocketContext webSocketContext);

/// <summary>
/// Process request method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current http context.</param>
public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    HttpResponse response = null;

    // Get the request and response context.
    response = context.Response;

    // If the request is a web socket protocol
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
         // Process the request.
         ProcessWebSocketRequest(context);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Process the request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="httpContext">The http context.</param>
private void ProcessWebSocketRequest(System.Web.HttpContext httpContext)
{
     HttpResponse response = null;

     // Get the request and response context.
     response = httpContext.Response;

     // Process the request asynchronously.
     httpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWebSocketRequestAsync);
}

/// <summary>
/// Process the request asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="webSocketContext">The web socket context.</param>
/// <returns>The task to execute.</returns>
private async Task ProcessWebSocketRequestAsync(System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocketContext webSocketContext)
{
     await Nequeo.Threading.AsyncOperationResult<bool>.
         RunTask(() =>
         {
             // Process the request.
             WebSocketContext(webSocketContext);
         });
}
```

If you are using a stand-alone server (this can be implemented as a Windows Service) then you can use `System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext` to handle 'WebSocket' connections through `HttpListenerContext`, sample:

```
/// <summary>
/// The on web socket context event handler, triggered when a new connection is established or data is present. Should be used when implementing a new connection.
/// </summary>
public event Nequeo.Threading.EventHandler<System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext> OnWebSocketContext;

/// <summary>
/// On http context action handler.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current http context.</param>
private void OnHttpContextHandler(HttpListenerContext context)
{
     HttpListenerRequest request = null;
     HttpListenerResponse response = null;

     // Get the request and response context.
     request = context.Request;
     response = context.Response;

     // If the request is a web socket protocol
     if (request.IsWebSocketRequest)
     {
          // Process the web socket request.
          ProcessWebSocketRequest(context);
     }
}

/// <summary>
/// Process the web socket protocol request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current http context.</param>
private async void ProcessWebSocketRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
     HttpListenerResponse response = null;

     // Get the request and response context.
     response = context.Response;

     // When calling `AcceptWebSocketAsync` the negotiated subprotocol 
     // must be specified. This sample assumes that no subprotocol  was requested. 
     HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);

     // Send the web socket to the handler.
     if (OnWebSocketContext != null)
          OnWebSocketContext(this, webSocketContext);
}
```

Once a request has been received you would start a conversation, sample.

```
/// <summary>
/// On WebSocket context.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
private async void OnWebSocketContext(System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext context)
{    
     WebSocket webSocket = null;

     try
     {
         // Get the current web socket.
         webSocket = context.WebSocket;

         CancellationTokenSource receiveCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
         byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

         // While the WebSocket connection remains open run a 
         // simple loop that receives data and sends it back.
         while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
         {
             // Receive the next set of data.
             ArraySegment<byte> arrayBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer);
             WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(arrayBuffer, receiveCancelToken.Token);

             // If the connection has been closed.
             if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
             {
                  break;
             }
             else
             {
                  // Start conversation.
             }
        }

        // Cancel the receive request.
        if (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
             receiveCancelToken.Cancel();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up by disposing the WebSocket.
        if (webSocket != null)
            webSocket.Dispose();
    }
}
```